# How to multiply two numbers in a string

Tags: php

I have a string like "1X6TAB". Now I apply some regular expression to this string to remove "TAB" and replacing "X" with "*", so my final string will be "1*6". The expected result is "6", but I get "1*6" as the result.

**Code:**

```
Regexonlynumber("1X6TAB");
function Regexonlynumber($number){
    $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9.X]/", '', $number);
    echo str_replace('X',"*",$number);die;
}
```

Comment: You are only echoing a string here.  Multiplication won't magically happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), which will also be able to compute more complex expressions:

```
Regexonlynumber("3X6-13TAB");
function Regexonlynumber($number){
    $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9.X\-\+\/]/", '', $number);
    $str = str_replace('X',"*",$number);
    eval("\$result = {$str};");
    echo $str . " = " . $result . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Using eval may have worse performance than other solutions. And it may have security concerns. (execution of random code, if the input is not checked properly)

Comment: Agree, but i'm terrified to imagine that if business would like to have full-scale expression parser - to implement it myself in PHP side. Besides - why should I do that, if `eval()` exactly does that ?

Comment: if performance and security are a big issue, then it might be better to implement it yourself (or there might be already a library to do it). But in this case, as long as you triple check you regex when accepting user-input, it's a good solution.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `str_replace()`, you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by `'X'` delimiter, then use [`array_product()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php).

```
Regexonlynumber("1X6TAB");
function Regexonlynumber($number){
    $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9.X]/", '', $number);
    echo array_product(explode('X', $number));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Just add one step more to explode and multiply, like this:

```
<?php
    function Regexonlynumber($number){
        $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9.X]/", '', $number);
        $arr = explode("X", $number);
        echo $arr[0]*$arr[1];
    }
    Regexonlynumber("2X6TAB");
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/930238).

You can even just do it like:

```
function Regexonlynumber($number){
    $arr = explode("X", $number);
    echo $arr[0]*$arr[1];
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/930245).

Answer (score 2):

### Regexonlynumber() function help you to to get product of numbers from string

**array_product() Function :-**  The array_product() function calculates and returns the product of an array.

**str_split() Function :-**  The str_split() function splits a string into an array.

```
<?php
    function Regexonlynumber($number){
        $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $number);
        echo array_product(str_split($number));
    }

    Regexonlynumber("1X6TAB");
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Check solution"?

Comment: "Try solution" is not better than "Check solution". You should be including an explanation with your answers, not just a blob of code.